# TypeInitializationException in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I'm going to create a student information system based on a tutorial. 
As soon as a user wants to add a new student to the database the following exception occurs.

I tried to learn something about TypeInitializationException and I understand a little by its name.. but I can't get it totally. Besides, the exception is absent from the tutorial I'm following.. I'm new in this type of OOP programming and handling errors. I included my database connection and database access class below..

[image: exception pic]

**My `DB_Connection` class**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace studentInformationSystem
{
    class DB_Connection
    {
        public static SqlConnection NewConnection;
        public static string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

        public static SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            NewConnection = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            return NewConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

**My `DB_Access` class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace studentInformationSystem
{
    class DB_Access
    {
        public SqlConnection conn;
        public DB_Access()
        {
            conn = DB_Connection.getConnection();
        }

        public void AddStudent(string regNo, string fName, string lName, string phoneNumber)
        {
            if(conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand newCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
            newCommand.Connection = conn; //why we use it..???
            newCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            newCommand.CommandText = "insert into student values('" + regNo + "','" + fName + "','" + lName + "','" + phoneNumber + "')";
            newCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

here is my connectionString

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

  <configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=SADID-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test1;Integrated Security=True" 
           providerName="System.Data.sqlClient" />  
    </connectionStrings>

  </configSections>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You should have a look at the exception details and possibly the inner exception to better understand what went wrong.

Comment: Show us the connection string. And is that Comic Sans you're using on that form? :)

Comment: Better remove those pictures, be specific.  There is nothing to do with first 2 images.

Comment: Show your connection string from config file

Comment: It is visible in your screenshot from the IntelliTrace trace.  Your app.exe.config file is screwed up.

Comment: i add my connection string above..
yes.. t8 is Comic Sans..i like t8 font.. :) @Gerrie Schenck

Comment: Did you say `conn.State.ToString() == "Closed"`? What's wrong with `conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In your case:**

This means that the following line fails:

```
public static string ConString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
```

Make sure that no exception happens here! Since this line is executed as part of `DB_Connection`'s type initialization, the exception occurs when you first access `DB_Connection`, which happens at `DB_Connection.getConnection()` - since you have no other (critical) initialization logic for `DB_Connection`, it basically **has** to be that line.

I strongly recommend moving logic like initializing `ConString` to a method (something like `Init`), so you will have more control about what happens - and much easier debugging!

Going from there, I guess `ConnectionStrings["ConString"]` returns `null` or throws an exception itself - but you will find that out easily. ;)

**More general description, for people having *similar* problems:**

Whenever `TypeInitializationException` is thrown, check *all* initialization logic of the type you are referring to for the first time in the statement where the exception is thrown.

*Initialization logic* includes: the type's static constructor and (like in this case) field initialization.

If at this point you still have no idea where the actual exception (that then triggers `TypeInitializationException`) happens, you should consider moving all (or parts of your) initialization logic to an extra static method. When you now call this method manually (before you first access the type, of course) you can benefit from your IDEs debugging abilities and will, most importantly, get the **actual** exception thrown at your head.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your connection string is not valid. I don't know what's in your app.config file.

One way to do this is given bellow.

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="XYZ" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NameOfYourDb;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then ........

```
var connection = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XYZ"];
```

And don't forget to give a reference to System.Configuration.dll

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all that's going on is that your getConnection is creating a new Sql connection with the connection string you're holding in a dictionary. I'd guess it could be either:

- ConString is invalid in some way
- Your database isn't active

I'd use the debugger to check the value of ConString when the exception is thrown (check the 'locals' tab at the bottom). If you're convince that it is correct I'd guess that your Sql database isn't running or is somehow invalid. However, I don't have enough experience to say *how* to diagnose that.

Comment: all that should trigger different kinds of exception ;) but very good debugging suggestions!

Comment: @olydis actually all this problems will raise a `TypeInitializationException` since all of this would happen either in a static field initialization or in a static constructor

Comment: nope, NOTHING else happens during type initialization, notice that for example if `ConString` is invalid or something, this would result in an exception inside `getConnection` - there is NO static constructor for `DB_Connection`, so no, nothing else happens during initialization than the field init ;)

Comment: @olydis oups sorry I misread the code (thought the `getConnection` function was a static constructor), yep you're right

Comment: hehehe no worries, that is **exactly** what I first thought reading through his code - when I was already working on my answer I suddenly realized I was talking about a constructor that actually was a method :)

Answer (score 0):

App.config file parameters are wrong
If you provide like this it will work : I have tried and it got executed correctly :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name ="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=SADA-PC;Initial Catalog=StudentTest;Integrated Security=True"
           providerName ="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```